# Jupyter kernels disappeared in the new python virtual environment

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I created a new python virtual environment using

```
conda create --name myenv python=3.9
```

However, when I run `jupyter notebook`, the previous kernels related to other conda envs have disappeared and the only one left is `Python 3` kernel which corresponds to the current myenv.

Is it possible recover previous kernels?

Comment: Have you activated the env you want to use?

Comment: @AlessandroTogni Yes. Activated using `conda activate`. Previously no matter what env I use, the jupyter notebook will display all available kernels.